# how can a little led indicator work in a power cord - why doesn't it explode from 240v

Tags: led

my LED goes well when i use my little electronics kit but i have seen one in a power cord. it has 240v in it. why doesn't it burn out in the power cord.  there doesn't seem any room in the plug bit to have a resistor and to get rid of the heat if there is one.
Thanks. Kid friendly answer please.

Comment: its hidden in there somewhere and would also need a reverse blocking diode too. R may probably in the 200k range for a 1~2 mA just visible.

Comment: I agree with answers. But are you sure that it is actually a LED? Other types of light indicators exist.

Comment: Hi All, Hope this where I can add stuff.  I have been reading stuff and found: A normal red LED has Vf=1.8V and Imax = 25mA. So V=IR i get R=V-Vf/Imax=240-1.8/0.025=9288 ohms. I think i'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

A lot of those cords use neon lamps, not LEDs. Many neon lamps are designed to be powered by line voltage with minimal additional components -- a resistor is often sufficient.

Comment: You must have a series resistor with a neon lamp or very bad things will happen.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah, you're right. I thought some worked directly from line voltage but I must have remembered wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very much heat to dissipate.  With a current of 5 mA RMS, the power loss in a resistor would be 120 x .005 = 0.6 W.  With a half wave rectifier in series, that's now only 0.3 W.

Comment: How well do you think a 1/4 watt resistor would fare? 1/8 W?  Remember he said it was so small he can't find it.  Oh, and it's 240 V.

Comment: Actually, he said he didn't think there was room, not that he had cut open the plug and looked.  Since 1/4 and 1/8 both are smaller than 1/3, they will not work reliably.  I'm not recommending he build this.  He asked about the thermal issue, and I think I covered that.  It is possible with two 1/4 W resistors in series.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0.47uF capacitor in series. No power dissipation.

Comment: Yup. I see it done like that. I'd still put some resistance to help dissipate energy from voltage spikes from power line glitches that pass through the cap though. And of course a reverse diode across the LED to prevent LED damage from reverse voltage. It also won't work without the reverse diode because then it just becomes a peak detector.

Comment: However, the cap would have to be X or X2 rated for power line connection, and a cap of that value and rating will be considerably larger than a couple of resistors.

Comment: True. About a cubic centimeter, minimum volume needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an "AC" LED containing two back-to-back dies and a relatively high value series resistor. Or they could probably get away with just a high value resistor (eg. 240K) and an ordinary LED- cost is pared to the bone on such products.

The latter is a bit of an abusive situation for the LED it would dissipate much more power in the reverse breakdown (typically tens of volts to over 100V), but probably tolerable if the dissipation and temperature is kept reasonable.

More expensive solutions would probably result in the hapless engineer being cashiered unceremoniously (aka defenestrated).

Please don't fool with this stuff (mains voltage) if you're a kid and unsupervised by someone familiar with safety precautions.